# Possible to create bookmarklets in Firefox with parameters?

Tags: firefox, search, bookmarklet

It used to be possible to create bookmarklets in Firefox that accepted parameters.

For example, you could create a bookmarklet to open superuser.com and search for a term.  You could then assign the keyword ***super*** to launch the bookmarklet.  Then, if you entered ***super firefox*** into Firefox's address bar, it would perform a search on superuser.com for the term ***firefox***.

In current Firefox versions (61-63), I can no longer find a way to do this.  Is it still possible?

Comment: Regrettably, I find most old bookmarklets no longer work since v. 57, or possibly before, so I hope there is some answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried on Firefox 61 (Win10/64bit) and it worked exactly as you described. The URL just need a "%s" where the search term would go. Example:

```
Bookmark URL:
https://superuser.com/search?q=%s

Keyword:
super

Search:
super keyboard error
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right-click a search box and select "Add a Keyword for this Search...": https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar

The keyword you configure for the search box in the dialog that appears will function the same as the bookmarklet described in the question.